Bidirectional CLLLC DC-DC Converter - PLECS Secondary Side Synchronous Recification can't realize ZVS
My question is regarding a CLLLC bidirectional dc-dc converter. I am attempting to model one in PLECS and am having trouble realizing ZVS operation when I actively drive the secondary side to be synchronous with the primary in order to reduce condution losses during rectification. I am new to this topology and do not understand why current flowing through the body diode or through the channel of the FET would make any difference to the operation of the primary side currents.
One thing I noticed is there a small phase delay between Vs and Vp ~18nS @ 100kHz and full load such that Vs is brought high just before Vp and as a result secondary FET 1 begins reverse conducting a small amount of current just before primary FET1 turns on and starts conducting. I delayed the turn-on of secondary side as to allow the body diode to conduct first and then later (tried 10ns -> full 1/2 period 2.5us) conduct through channel. However if the secondary FET is at all turned on I lose ZVS on primary side.
For context, my understanding is that PLECS doesn't model drain to source capacitance in the FETs and uses a lookup table to calculate conduction and switching loss. So I expect if there is some amount of deadtime in the model the HS FET will begin reverse conducting when the LS turns off, the HS FET will be brought to 0 volts and after deadtime period it will turn-on @0V Vds and the lookup table will read 0 switching loss. All this is to say for the sake of the simulation the length of deadtime and magntiude of the magnetizing current does not matter as there is no capacitance to discharge. This happens when the secondary side is passively rectifiying. However, when I start driving the secondary side in synchronous, the primary side current reaches 0 during the middle of the deadtime and the HS FET stops reverse conducting before the deadtime is over causing a hard switch event.
All of this operation is at the resonant frequency 100kHz with duty cycle 0.5 and deadtime 30ns. Any thoughts about the circuit or the operation would be greatly appreciated

Here is a visual of what is happening during synchronous rectification: 
